# TOR will only open SOME onlion links

Tags: onion-routing, linux

I just installed linux on my laptop (parrot). I can access a lot of onion links via Tor, but for some reason places like Empire and Dread are just not loading. I tried the exact same links on my android and they worked without any issue

what should I do?

Im new to linux so help would be appreciated!

thanks guys!

Comment: Are these v2 onion addresses? If so, I believe v2 services can have instability problems. If you're sure that the websites are up, just try again later, and maybe ask the site operator to upgrade to a v3 service.

Comment: Chances are the website are down. It's no different than any other browser. If the website is down then there's nothing you can do about it.